# AS3: Add layer overlay on top of everything?

Tags: actionscript-3, overlay

I want to add some extra texturing for my current game, let's say an overlayed grunge texture on top of everything.

My entire project (except background image) is set on a Main Class.

Is it Possible? How?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just disable any mouse input on the overlay and it will be like its not even there.

```
public function LuckyHitBeta()
{
    ...

    var overlay:Sprite = new Sprite();
    overlay.addChild( /* your texture goes here  as a Bitmap */ );
    overlay.mouseEnabled = false;
    overlay.mouseChildren = false;
    addChild(overlay);
}
```

Comment: Weird, no matter if I link the object to as3 or call it by it's name, I will always get `Access of undefined property artGrunge1.` Is on the library, maybe I have to call it locally?

Answer (score 0):

Cant entirely remember the correct syntax but couldn't you just do:

```
import flash.display.Stage;
public class GlobalStage extends MovieClip

public static var theStage:Stage;
public static var theRoot:MovieClip;

public function GlobalStage() {
    theStage = this.stage;
    theRoot = this.root;
}
var grunge:MovieClip = new Grunge();
var topDepth:uint = theStage.numChildren()-1;
theStage.addChildAt(grunge, topDepth)
```

Comment: The `addChild` function will automatically add it to the top of the stack, so no need to use `addChildAt` unless you want it further down.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting this: `Attempted access of inaccessible method numChildren through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage.`

Comment: @atonparker - true, I think I only use this in for loops for adding multiples objects

Comment: @Gabriel Meono - whoops sorry, forgot stage cant be directly accessed from within a class. Edited, but messy and atonparker's answer is much neater